# How to unscope multiple models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, acts-as-paranoid

I am trying to unscope multiple model as below
User Model which has acts_as_paranoid

```
class User
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_one :category
  has_one :brand
  has_one :item         

  INDEXED_FIELDS = {
    only: [:name],
    include: {
      category: { only: [:name] },
      item: { only:[:name] },
      brand: { only: [:name]},
    }
  }

  def custom_json
    Category.unscoped do
      Item.unscoped do
        Brand.unscoped do
          self.as_json(INDEXED_FIELDS)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

User model has following association which also has acts_as_paranoid

Sample Category model, Brand and Item model have same code

```
class Category
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Can I do this dynamically with 'N' number of models, like iterating over array as below

```
def custom_json
  [Category, Item, Brand].each do 
    # do unscoping 
  end
end
```

Association looks like

Comment: What exactly you want to do by unscoping??

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy I want exclude default scope conditions from multiple models

Comment: That's fine. But what is the scenario of doing unscoping multiple models at a time. We can do while quering right?

Comment: Please provide `Category`, `Item`, `Brand` model files. So we could see relationships between them

Comment: When we call `self.as_json(INDEXED_FIELDS)`, it queries association to build json, I want unscope association and build the json.

Comment: `self..as_json` is custom implemented or from any library?

Comment: Updated question to have model relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you may have is to unscope the class manually, by setting `default_scopes` to `[]`, and then putting it back.

```
classes_to_unscope = [Category, Item, Brand]
# remove default_scopes, saving them in previous_scopes
previous_scopes = classes_to_unscope.map do |klazz| 
  scopes = klazz.default_scopes
  klazz.default_scopes = []
  scopes
end 
self.as_json(INDEXED_FIELDS)
# put default_scopes back
classes_to_unscope.each_with_index do |klazz, i|
  klazz.default_scopes = previous_scopes[i]
end
```

Comment: What is `klazz.default_scoping`, its giving error as undefined method?

Comment: Sorry, typo, it was `default_scopes`

Answer (score 0):

As extra method:

```
def unscope_all(*models, &block)
    # the order does not matter, but preserve it
    blocks = [block] + models.reverse.map do |model|
      proc do |inner_block|
        model.unscoped { inner_block.call }
      end
    end

    blocks.inject do |inner, outer|
      proc { outer.call(inner) }
    end.call
  end
```

Then you would use it:

```
unscope_all(Category, Item, Brand) do 
    # do unscoping 
  end
```

**unscoped pitfall**: when leaving the block you loose the "unscopability", so make sure you don't return a relation (it won't be unscoped). Instead you have to resolve it in the block (e.g. by returning an array `where(...).to_a`.